# i want to iterate the dates from the json i am receiving in the server response

Tags: ios, json, swift4

I am getting a response from the server which contains show dates which I want to iterate how can I do that. The problem is that the key "instances" has a value of the object and that object contains the key value pair for the dates which I want to store. plz help

this is the JSON response:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "XYFYyvu2bckt",
            "theater_id": "clzEVgztkcWB",
            "theater_audi_id": "N9iDgooiCW6N",
            "movie_lang_id": "B9x98d4IEpCt",
            "booking_start_date": null,
            "instances": {
                "2018-04-18": [
                    {
                        "id": "vpcr2c9N12tL",
                        "show_time": "20:30:00"
                    }
                ],
                "2018-04-19": [
                    {
                        "id": "X9kPcU7SLzrC",
                        "show_time": "20:30:00"
                    }
                ],
                "2018-04-20": [
                    {
                        "id": "pFnFtXO5jKWp",
                        "show_time": "20:30:00"
                    }
                ],
                "2018-04-21": [
                    {
                        "id": "hQuBFADUHeyS",
                        "show_time": "20:30:00"
                    }
                ],
                "2018-04-22": [
                    {
                        "id": "vzXzOZvvKf9F",
                        "show_time": "20:30:00"
                    }
                ],
                "2018-04-23": [
                    {
                        "id": "kAhzwyqoVGF4",
                        "show_time": "20:30:00"
                    }
                ],
                "2018-04-24": [
                    {
                        "id": "wVXRjq6LrZJm",
                        "show_time": "20:30:00"
                    }
                ],
                "2018-04-25": [
                    {
                        "id": "6hA1qglyP1Hf",
                        "show_time": "20:30:00"
                    }
                ],
                "2018-04-26": [
                    {
                        "id": "NoLPN8RQNRXV",
                        "show_time": "20:30:00"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
```

}

here is what i had tried:

```
  _ = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (Data, response, error) in
            if Data != nil{
                do{
                    let access = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: Data!, options: []) as! [String:NSArray]
                    Completion(access)
                    for i in access["data"]!{
                        let a = i

                        let b = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: a as Any, options: .prettyPrinted)

                        let d = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: b, options: []) as! [String: Any]
                        let e = d["instances"]

                        for (key, timeObj)  in d["instances"]{
                            print(key)
                        }

                    }
                }catch let e{
                    print(e)
                }
            }
            }.resume()
```

Comment: Did you try anything? Because JSON, is just Dictionary, Array, String & Number. Nothing out of basic developers skills.

Comment: i am new to swift and i have edited my question for better understanding

Comment: What's the point of `b` & `d`? Don't use `NSArray` in Swift 3+. Learn to debug: Which lines work? Which doesn't? Then come back here with theses info.

Comment: ... and don't use `Data` (capitalized) as a variable name. It could clash with the Swift 3+ `Data` struct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
let access = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: Data!, options: []) as! [String:Any] 
if let data = access["data"] as? [[String:Any]] , let instances = data[0]["instances"] as? [String:Any] {
  print(instances)
}
```